# Java-based interpreter for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, antlr, interpreter, bytecode

As a project in school i have to make a JavaScript interpreter. (Everything incl. the entire backend has to be made by me).

Everything has to be written in Java - i use ANTLR for parsing and generating ASTs.

currently i can parse some .js code into an AST - and therefore need to translate this AST into som kind of intermediate-representation that can be executed on a bytecode machine.

I have some experience writing compilers for statically typed languages, but im very much in doubt how to proceed from here since JS is a dynamically typed language.

If you can give me some good advices on how to proceed i would be gratefull!

Personally i think i have to make the bytecode-machine first and then make the IR fit this machine afterwards. Unfortunatly i cant really find any good tutorials on how to write a bytecode-machine.

PS. im familiar with following books on the topic :

"modern compiler implementation in Java (Appel)",
"Programming language processors in Java (Watt & Brown)", 
"Language implementation patterns (Parr)"

Regards Sune

Comment: Out of curiosity, what class is asking you to write a whole Javascript interpreter?

Comment: Crikey that's ambitious for a school project!

Answer (score 0):

*If you only want to execute the javascript you do not need to transform the AST into IR and then into (some?) bytecode that would also force you to do a bytecode executer.*

Why not just execute the javascript AST in a java "engine"? You can store all values as a `Map<String, Object>` and interpret them as you walk the AST. A new function get an environment/context (a new `Map<...>`).

If you cannot find a value in the current context you will have to fall back on the global context  (=`Map`).

For the "dynamic" behaviour: If you need an `double` for an addition you only parse the `Object.toString()` value to an `double` using the standard way (more dynamic than that is hard to get :) ):

```
String value = contextMap.get(key); 
Double dvalue = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
....
```

Comment: That is my backup plan if everything else fails - i should be quite easy to implement. But i want to go for the better (In terms of execution speed and further optimization improvements) bytecode-execution

Comment: I wouldn't use strings for the backing values -- Javascript numbers are doubles.

Comment: It *is* easy to implement compared to the route you want to go! :) (@Sean: updated to `Object`)